# ssh terminal inserting terminal program name

Tags: c, ssh, terminal

As part of a academic course I've been using SSH to communicate with a operating system I'm developing on. (see www.xinu.cs.purdue.edu if you're curious) I'm seeing some really weird side-effects of my bad programming and am hoping someone can explain how it's happening.

The error which I've now fixed is that I listed the parameters out of order in a function that creates a new thread) The parameters messed up are the function name and its priority which both don't currently effect operation (there is only one process wanting to run).

My concern is that when I printed the process list (which contains invalid name and priority) to the console, my terminal would insert the name of  **my** ssh program into the terminal on **my** end. 
For example this would be the last few lines of my terminal:

```
xsh $ ps
Pid Name             State Prio Ppid Stack Base Stack Ptr  Stack Size
--- ---------------- ----- ---- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
  0 prnull           ready    0    0 0x0EFDEFFC 0x0EFDEEB0     8192
  1 rdsproc          susp   200    0 0x0EFDCFFC 0x0EFDCFC8    16384
  3 Main process     recv    20    2 0x0EFC8FFC 0x0EFC8F64    65536
  4 shell            recv    50    3 0x0EFB8FFC 0x0EFB8C7C     8192
  5 F                 curr  30548    4 0x0EFD8FFC 0x0EFD8D88     8192
xsh $ Bitvise SSH Client
```

I did not type "Bitvise SSH Client" but I can backspace it out (And I can't delete anything before the $). The processes in error is listed as F. Furthermore if I switch ssh clients, my new program's name (for example puTTy) is inserted. Also if multiple processes are initialized wrong, the terminal program name is inserted once per bad process. (And its occurs whatever the process does and whatever state it's in)

What information can the erroring program can send across SSH that makes my computer print out its program name? I don't remember any escape character to cause that and I never told the other computer what my terminal program was called.

Comment: Exchange of client and server identification strings is a part of normal ssh connection set up.  Nothing needs to be sent across the channel to get the ID string once the connection has been established.

Comment: Ah, that certainly answers one question. So how did it cause my client identification string to be printed onto the terminal then? It seems like it was my end that wrote the text on the terminal, given that I could only delete that  and only that text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incorrect program name probably contains a Ctrl-E character (ASCII 005, the ENQ character). This causes PuTTY and other terminal emulators to answer with their program name. See [this entry](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-puttyputty) in the [PuTTY FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html), for example. The effect is as if you had typed in the name of the program.